# How change UITab bar position to top?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have two view controllers and embed with tab bar controller. It's working fine, but i want to show the `tabbar` frame on top of the view. I changed the frame to top it's also working fine. But the problem is in bottom it's showing some `whitecolor` view at the bottom `tabbar` position.

How to remove this bottom view?
[image: See the bottom view on this pic]

My Code is

In `viewDidLoad`

```
//Set selected item colour white on tab bar
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
//Set tab bar title position
UITabBarItem.appearance().titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -12.5)
//Tab bar title font
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([kCTFontAttributeName as NSAttributedStringKey: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15.0)], for: .normal)



override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    //Set tab bar frame on top position
    tabBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tabBar.frame.size.width, height: tabBar.frame.size.height)
//        tabBar.isTranslucent = false
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //Set navigation bar translucent
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
}
```

Comment: you can use https://github.com/PageMenu/PageMenu library without adding tabor

Comment: I can't reproduce this. https://ibb.co/dPoqyJ - my screenshot. Probably, where is an odd Tab Bar in a storyboard. Can you provide more details or share a sample code?

Comment: @ llkenny  I provided the complete code to change the frame of tabbar and please tell me what type of code do you required

Comment: I used your code and it works fine. You can check out my sample code: https://github.com/llkenny/how-change-uitab-bar-position-to-top. Item2 screen looks fine, but on Item1 screen i added an additional Tab Bar, and it looks like your problem. I think the problem is in your storyboard.

Comment: Ok, i think, i got it. Change your bottom constraint to superview but not to SafeArea.

Comment: @ llkenny Finally i solved my issue. Thank you very much for your response. I added image view  through storyboard, that's the main problem.

Comment: Good! You're welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added image view for background in story board, That's why i'm getting this problem. I removed image view in storyboard and added background image through programmatically.

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: hdpi.png")!)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)
view.insertSubview(imageView, at: 0)
```

Now my problem is solved...